# Rails 4: custom wrapper method around Devise's edit profile page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'd like to write a custom method around Devise's edit profile page. I'd like it to be run before the edit page is loaded and after it is submitted. However, my code doesn't seem to be working:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :check_tutor, only: :edit

  private
    def check_tutor
      if current_user.is_tutor
        current_user.build_tutor if current_user.tutor.nil?
      else
        current_user.tutor.destroy
      end
    end
 end
```

Any ideas as to why this may be? Thanks!

Comment: Did you add this to routes?

Comment: No, do I need to make this refer to /user/edit?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17993705/2422778

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For devise to pick up you controller you need to do following change in routes

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "registrations"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding edit action to this controller

```
def edit
  super
end
```

For the filter to execute after the form is submitted, you will have to add

```
before_filter :check_tutor, only: [:edit, :update]

def update
  super
end
```

Comment: Could you try restarting the server?

Comment: Did that already :P  ... this might have to do with routes. My registrations_controller.rb doesn't match the /users/edit page

Answer (score 0):

you might also want to consider an around_filter http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#after-filters-and-around-filters. i'd show some sample code but i'm not sure if you're trying to build the tutor in the before and destroy it in the after [as needed] or are these actions supposed to run on both sides of the controller action.